# How to type functions in useRef hook with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component:

```
interface MyRef {
  foo: () => Promise<string>;
  bar: () => Promise<string>;
}

const Component: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const myRef = useRef<MyRef>({
    foo: async () => 'foo',
    bar: async () => myRef.current.foo(),
  });

  return <p>Comp</p>;
};
```

TypeScript complains that `'myRef' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)`.

How should I do so that TypeScript knows the type of `myRef.current.foo()`?

Comment: Look at what `useRef` returns: `function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;`. You can use that type explicitly yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the type for `myRef` as follows.

```
const myRef: MutableRefObject<MyRef> = useRef<MyRef>({
    foo: async () => "foo",
    bar: async () => myRef.current.foo()
  });
```